# Как использовать курсор?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Есть процедура на вставку:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BSOs_InsertBso]
    @Domain_username nvarchar(50)='Max'
    ,@ProductCode int=100
    ,@BsoNumber int=12000
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[BSOs]
           ([BsoCode]
           ,[BsoNumber]
           ,[Owner]
           ,[FullNumber])   
    Select 
        bt.bsoCode          
        ,@BsoNumber
        ,@Domain_username
        , bt.BsoPrefix + right('00000000000'+cast(@BsoNumber as varchar(10)), NumberLen)
    From   dbo.BsoTypes bt
    inner join BsoToInsProduct bp on bp.BsoCode = bt.BsoCode
    where @ProductCode = bp.InsProductCode  
END
```

Теперь мне надо создать процедуру которая добавляет в таблицу `[dbo].[BSOs]`
диапазон   16000 - 16100 номеров бсо(записи) по каждому продукту через курсор.
  То есть задав параметр автоматический добавлял в таблицу
Сделать курсор с параметрами, например :

```
DECLARE @Domain_username nvarchar(50)='Alex'
    ,@StartBsoNumber int=16000
    ,@Count int =100 -- количество бСО которые нужно создать
```

Как создать процедуру с используя курсор? Или синтаксис курсора в моем случаи

Comment: а зачем курсор? Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вам надо создать `N` схожих записей, отличающихся только по полю `BsoCode` (ну и соответственно `FullNumber`)?

Comment: @cyadvert, курсор надо чтобы использовалось как цикл и добавлял в таблицу записи

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос - то можно и без курсора обойтись.... только ответьте, правильно ли я Вас понял - все те записи, что будут созданы, будут почти идентичны. Разница лишь будет в изменяющимся на единицу поле `BsoNumber` и `FullNumber`. Так?

Comment: @cyadvert, разница будет и по продукту(BsoCode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывать 100 раз хранимку ради вставки 100 - это не SQL-way.

Вам не нужен курсор. Вам нужна последовательность чисел от 16000 до 16099. Ее можно сгенерировать как:

```sql
DECLARE @startnum INT=16000
DECLARE @endnum INT=@startnu + 99

;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
SELECT * FROM gen
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

этот CTE можно подмешать прямо в ваш INSERT примерно так:

```sql
DECLARE @startnum INT=@StartBsoNumber
DECLARE @endnum INT=@startnum + @Count - 1
;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BSOs]
       ([BsoCode]
       ,[BsoNumber]
       ,[Owner]
       ,[FullNumber])   
Select 
    bt.bsoCode          
    ,gen.num
    ,@Domain_username
    , bt.BsoPrefix + right('00000000000'+cast(get.num as varchar(10)), NumberLen)
From   dbo.BsoTypes bt
inner join BsoToInsProduct bp on bp.BsoCode = bt.BsoCode
cross join gen
where @ProductCode = bp.InsProductCode  
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

Comment: ok  а как сделать это по каждому продукту(BsoCode)

Comment: (@ProductCode)  такого параметра не задали же

Comment: @Zhandos уберите where `@ProductCode = bp.InsProductCode`  - и сработает сразу для всех BsoToInsProduct

Comment: насчет `@ProductCode` - вы же собирались вызывать `BSOs_InsertBso` из той процедуры, которую вы собирались писать. что вы хотели передать как `@ProductCode`?

Comment: спасибо заработал

Comment: О! Класс. Я не пробовал никогда этот `WITH .. as()`. Намного проще моего варианта. Ща пару своих процедур переделаю! @PashaPash +1

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - надо создать `N` схожих записей, отличающихся лишь по полю `BsoNumber` (ну и соответственно `FullNumber`). Причем `BsoNumber` будет увличиваться на единицу, начиная с `@StartBsoNumber`.

Если так, то можно обойтись и без курсора.

1. Надо сделать так, чтобы Ваш `SELECT .... FROM dbo.BsoTypes JOIN BsoToInsProduct ...` возвращал `N` одинаковых записей. Обычно я делаю `JOIN` с какой-нибудь офигительно большой таблицей. Ее содержимое не важно, важно кол-во строк.
   И в этот `SELECT` поставить `TOP @Count`
   Ну например:

   ```
   SELECT TOP @Count [list-of-fields]
   FROM   dbo.BsoTypes bt
   inner join BsoToInsProduct bp on bp.BsoCode = bt.BsoCode
   INNER JOIN logTable l ON id BETWEEN 1 AND 99999999
   where @ProductCode = bp.InsProductCode
   ```

   Таким образом мы получаем почти то, что надо. Не хватает лишь правильного счетчика для `BsoNumber`.
2. Включаем автоматическую нумерацию в `SELECT`. Функция `RANK() OVER ()`.

   ```
   SELECT TOP @Count 
   bt.bsoCode,
   ((RANK() OVER (ORDER BY bso.id))+@StartBsoNumber),
   @Domain_username,
   bt.BsoPrefix + right('00000000000'+cast(((RANK() OVER (ORDER BY bso.id))+@StartBsoNumber) as varchar(10)), NumberLen)
   FROM   dbo.BsoTypes bt
   inner join BsoToInsProduct bp on bp.BsoCode = bt.BsoCode
   INNER JOIN logTable l ON id BETWEEN 1 AND 99999999
   where @ProductCode = bp.InsProductCode
   ```

   Проверьте, если запрос возвращает то, что Вам надо, можно его в `INSERT INTO`воткнуть.